# Java serialize byte[] for hbase

Tags: java, serialization, hbase, arrays

I want to store an `UUID` in Hbase using Java.

Today, I write it as a `String` of 36 characters, but it takes too much space. I need to optimize. I want to write a raw `byte[16]`, but it is not `Serializable`.

**Is there any** easy **way to do that?**

Am I doing something terribly wrong? I feel there is something I do not understand well enough. :(

Thanks

---

Here is my approach, which do not work because `Type '...UserId' does not have a serializer`:

```
public class UserId implements Serializable {    
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private byte[] uuid;

  public UserId() {      }

  public UserId(byte[] uuid) { this.uuid = uuid; }

  public UserId(String uuid) { this(UUID.fromString(uuid)); }

  public UserId(UUID uuid) {
    this(uuid.getMostSignificantBits(), uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
  }

  public UserId(long msb, long lsb) {
    this.uuid = Bytes.concat(Longs.toByteArray(msb), Longs.toByteArray(lsb));
  }

  public byte[] getUuid() {
    return uuid;
  }

  public void setUuid(byte[] uuid) {
    this.uuid = uuid;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(uuid);
    return new UUID(bb.getLong(), bb.getLong()).toString();
  }


  private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    out.write(uuid);
  }

  private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    in.readFully(uuid);
  }

  private void readObjectNoData() throws ObjectStreamException {}
}
```

Comment: Is "Longs" from Guava ? Also, is "Type '...UserId' does not have a serializer" the error message you get on your ide with that class ? Where did you get that Byte.concat method ?

Comment: Yes, both `Longs` and `Bytes` are from Guava: `import com.google.common.primitives.Bytes;
import com.google.common.primitives.Longs;`

Comment: The `"Type '...UserId' does not have a serializer"`  error message is from a custom Exception. It was implemented a while ago by somebody else.

Comment: You should give the full stack trace of the error if it comes from custom libraries. Maybe you need some kind of special "Serializer" class, bound to this one, in order to serialize it ? Also, you should try to use two longs "msl" and "lsl" (most significant and less significant "long") instead of byte array. Like in one of your constructor. I don't know how the serialization process will know how many bytes it must write, and how many it must read. Also, be carefull in which order you put read and write for the longs (msl first or lsl first).

Comment: Finally I can get the data in Hbase, but I can't read back the date `20151124`. The `byte[]` in key corresponds to the `value`. 4w\x00 **;\xA1\x5C\x1A\x914J\xB4\x92\xC04=\xBB\xA8\x93\xA1** 4 **20151124** \x00 column=i:country, timestamp=1448362136391, value="**3ba15c1a-9134-4ab4-92c0-343dbba893a1**"

Comment: I don't really understand... which byte contains the value ? Isn"t the timestamp enough ?

Comment: Real data looks like this: ROW `4w\x00\xA1\x5C\x1A\x914J\xB4\x92\xC04=\xBB\xA8\x93\xA1420151124\x00` -- COLUMN+CELL `column=i:country, timestamp=1448362136391, value="FR"` ; I have replaced value in order to validate the `byte[]` part from the ROW (key).

Comment: @Asoub, thanks for your help, but for the time being I've fixed the problem without using `UserId`. But I still do not know how to fix it using `UserId`. I will be back in the next days when I will better understand the problem. Thanks.